# проблема выбора кратчайшего пути из 3 различных точек до фиксированной точки yandex map api

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, route

**Задача** из 3х заданных координатами точек выбрать точку путь от которой до заданной точки назначения будет наименьшим.

Задача выполняется силами Yandex Map Api.

JS код:

```js
 ymaps.ready(function () {  
            var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                    center: [55.91765312, 37.80059937], 
                    zoom: 16
                 }),
                myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
                     geometry: {
                        type: "Point", // тип геометрии - точка
                        coordinates: [55.91764107, 37.80413989] // координаты точки
                     }
                }),
                brigades=<?php print_r($brJson)?>,
                accidentPlace=<?php print_r($dist)?>,
                lengthOfPathes=new Array(),
                timeOfPathes=new Array(),
                arr=new Array();
            map.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
            //**Здесь начинаются проблемы**
            for(var key in brigades){
                ymaps.route([brigades[key],accidentPlace]).then(
                  function(route){
                   arr.push(route.getLength());
                   },
                  function(error){
                      alert('Error'+error.msg);
                  },
                );
             }
            
            arr.push(11.45);
            arr.push(16);
            console.log(arr);
            console.log(arr[2]);
            
      
        });
```

В цикле for in происходит заполнение массива длинами пути, но почему то в консоль выводится массив arr в таком виде:

```
(2) [11.45, 16]
    0: 11.45
    1: 16
    2: 467.83
    3: 1572.84
    4: 1555.48
    length: 5
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

PHP:

```html
<?php
         echo 45;
         $distances=[
             [55.91494935, 37.81120928],
             [55.91984168, 37.81219633],
             [55.92274545, 37.81472833]
         ];
         $brigade=[
             'kostkinTeam'=>[55.91938593, 37.81674452],
             'svodinTeam'=>[55.91207938, 37.81317238],
             'msuTeam'=>[55.91765312, 37.80059937],
         ];
         
         $brJson=json_encode($brigade);
         $item= mt_rand(0, count($distances)-1);
         $dist=json_encode($distances[$item]);
         $distancesJson=json_encode($distances);
       
 ?>
```

Доступа к элементам 2-4 нет, при попытке доступа получаю undefiened.

Помогите понять в чём здесь проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ymaps.route` - асинхронная функция. Вам надо подождать пока все запросы выполнятся.

```js
var arr = [];
var promises = [];

for (var key in brigades) {
    var routePromise = ymaps.route([brigades[key], accidentPlace]).then(
        function (route) {
            arr.push(route.getLength());
        },
        function (error) {
            alert('Error' + error.msg);
        }
    );

    promises.push(routePromise);
}

ymaps.vow.all(promises).then(function () {
    console.log(arr);
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное решение!Очень помогло!